# Display:none для обьекта при клике

Tags: php, html, css

Есть такой код 
 
 `echo "<td>" . '<a style = "text-decoration: none; color: red; " href="?delete_image='. $cat['id'] . '">Ջնջել</а>'."</td>";`

При клике он удаляет эту запись, я хочу сделать так чтобы при клике этой же записи присваивался display:none чтобы его не было видно, как реализовать не понимаю.

Comment: вопрос в том, хотите ли вы это состояние как-то сохранять в БД или нет. Или быть может в пользовательском хранилище. Или же просто скрыть одноразово, а после обновления страницы все снова появится.

Comment: код для удаления уже существует, при нажатии на эту кнопку зьапись удаляется но в таблице до рефреша страницы она видна, я хочу его просто скрыть. А дальше уже при перезагрузке его и не будет.

Comment: js используйте. добавьте обработчик события клика на эту ссылку, в нем найдите родительскую строку и либо вообще удалите ее, либо скройте. на jquery это совсем просто будет `$(this).closest('tr').remove()`, но поскольку тэгов js  у вас нет, то я не знаю нативный вам нужен или нет.

Comment: Не имею знаний в js, можно как-нибуддь это реализовать чистым html/css/php?

Comment: без js не сделать